# Colspan styling in nested tables failed

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I have a problem with nested tables. In my Company we have an old website wich is based on an table layout. I want to add dynamicaly a new td in one tr. If this td is set, in the other tr's i will set on the last td a colspan=2.
If i do this, my table looks like this:

|----|-|-------|--|---|-|-|

|----|-|-------|--|---|-|-|

|----|-|-------|--|---|-|-|

instead of looking like this:

|---|-|----|--|---|-|-----|

|---|-|----|--|---|-|-----|

|---|-|----|--|---|-|-----|

( - only defined as width not as colspan)

This is sample markup from my code:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
    <tbody>
        <!-- Headline tr -->
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" valign="middle" nowrap align="left" colspan="7"> 
                Titel 
            </td>
            <!-- New dynamic Field -->
            <td nowrap align="right"> 
                <img src="example.gif" width="15px" height="15px"/>               
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap align="left"> 
                Name
            </td>
            <td> 
                :
            </td>
            <td width="50%" align="left"> 
                <input readonly value="test" />
            </td>
            <td > 
                <img src="blank.gif" />
            </td>
            <td nowrap align="left"> 
                Number
            </td>
            <td> 
                :
            </td>
            <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="2"> 
                <input readonly value="test" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap align="left"> 
                Name
            </td>
            <td> 
                :
            </td>
            <td width="50%" align="left"> 
                <input readonly value="test" />
            </td>
            <td > 
                <img src="blank.gif" />
            </td>
            <td nowrap align="left"> 
                Number
            </td>
            <td> 
                :
            </td>
            <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="2"> 
                <input readonly value="test" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap align="left"> 
                Name
            </td>
            <td> 
                :
            </td>
            <td width="50%" align="left"> 
                <input readonly value="test" />
            </td>
            <td > 
                <img src="blank.gif" />
            </td>
            <td nowrap align="left"> 
                Number
            </td>
            <td> 
                :
            </td>
            <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="2"> 
                <input readonly value="test" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This table is nested in a table with `<table width="100%" height="100%">`

[image: This is what it looks like]

Whats the failure?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a different number of td in rows (tr) from the same parent table.
In your example, you have 8 (7+1) td in your first row and only 7 (5+2) in both others.
It may break your table..

Comment: Hey, yes in my markup i forgot the space td. I have edit my markup so it is now 6+2

Comment: Can you precise your problem ? only a problem of proportions ?

Comment: Yeah, if i do the colspan=2 on the last td it will look like in the screenshot. If i only set one td has no colspan=2 everything looks expected except this one td without colspan. I dont why.

Comment: On your screenshot, I noticed that your very last row has a very wide input probably wrapped by a td with a colspan of 5 or 6 !!! So you can't apply a colspan="2" to this one through js

Comment: Yeah in my last row the the last td (there are only 3) has an colspan of 6. I dont set the colspan with js, i set it with php.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. In my First row, the first td with colspan=7 dont need the width="100%". Now its functional.